# Laravel 5 form not working (not inserting data)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

```
        public function save()
 {
        //return \View::make('student.view');

        $validation= array(
                      'first_name'=>'required',

                      'email'=>'required'

                          );
        $v1= Validator::make(Input::all(),$validation);
```

I think it fails after this line and not inserting the data and it just again shows the form like as v1 fails and it goes to view file (form) after pressing the submit button.

```
        if( $v1->fails())
        {
        return Redirect::to('view')->withErrors($v1);
        }
        else
        { $poststudent=Input::all();
          $data = array('first_name'=>$poststudent['first_name'],
                         'last_name'=>$poststudent['last_name'],
                         'email'=>    $poststudent['email'],
                    'interested'=>    $poststudent['interested'], 
                         'skills'=>   $poststudent['skills']);

        $check=0;
        $check=DB::table('students')->insert($data);

        if($check > 0)
        {
        return Redirect::to('/');
        }
        else
        {
        return Redirect::to('/view');
        }

        }

        }
```

view.blade.php file is here  (in this, there is features of form):

```
   <form action="<?=URL::to('/save')?>" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


    <div class="form-group">
    <label for= "first_name"> FIRST NAME </label>
     <input name="FIRST NAME" type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="first name"/>
   </div>

  <br /><br />
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for= "last_name"> LAST NAME </label>
   <input name="LAST NAME" type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="LAST NAME"/>
  </div>

 <br /><br />
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for= "EMAIL"> EMAIL </label>
   <input name="EMAIL" type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="EMAIL"/>
   </div>



    <br /><br />
    <div >
    <label for= "INTERESTED"> INTERESTED </label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="INTERESTED" value="ANDROID DEVELOPER" />
    ANDROID DEVELOPER<br />
    <input type="radio" name="INTERESTED" value="WEB DEVELOPER" />
    WEB DEVELOPER<br />
    <input type="radio" name="INTERESTED" value="GAME DEVELOPER" />
    GAME DEVELOPER <br />
    <input type="radio" name="INTERESTED" value="JAVA DEVELOPER" />
    JAVA DEVELOPER<br />
   </div>

   <br /><br />
   <div >
   <label for= "SKILLS"> SKILLS </label><br />
   <textarea name="SKILLS" cols="50" rows="6"></textare a>
    </div>



   <br />
   <br />


   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="save" class="text" />


    </form>
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What isn't working? Are there any errors?

Comment: no . there is no error.. bt main problem is that. .. it is not showing the data inserted

Comment: what is your route method, where you posting your data?

Comment: when i insert the data in the form and then press submit button ... it comes back again to view page(form page) . and when i go to php my admin to check the inserted data. there was nothing inserted.

Comment: Route::post('/save',array('uses'=>'student@save')); this is my route methed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Blade view, you using element name in wrong way. e.g `name="Last Name"` You should use like:

```
<input name="last_name" type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="LAST NAME"/>
```

Then your this code will work.

```
$data = array('first_name'=>$poststudent['first_name'],
                         'last_name'=>$poststudent['last_name'],
                         'email'=>    $poststudent['email'],
                    'interested'=>    $poststudent['interested'], 
                         'skills'=>   $poststudent['skills']);
```

### Update

You also need to use

```
 public function save(Request $request)
```

and without

```
 $poststudent=Input::all();
```

use

```
 $poststudent = $request->all();
```

Comment: @deepsingh I just make some more suggestion, you can check it.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found.. bt i found this now.. what should i do now

Comment: add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` in top of your class.